# angular - invoke() on exising element undefined

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I've a div (id: dest) in which content is loaded via ajax using query.
I need to compile with angular the content of that div.

Here is the content loaded via ajax:
    
        {{myvar}}

I tried to do:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.myvar = "hello world!";
});

$("#dest").attr("data-ng-app", "myapp");
$("#dest").attr("data-ng-controller", "myctrl");

console.log(angular.element($("#dest")).size()); //always returns '1'

angular.element($("#dest")).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element($("#dest")).scope();
    $compile($("#dest"))(scope);
});
```

I'm sure that $("#dest") exists in dom when that code is executed but 
angular.element($("#dest")).injector() is always undefined.

I also tried to wait 15 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    angular.element($("#dest")).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($("#dest")).scope();
        $compile($("#dest"))(scope);
    });
}, 15000);
```

But the problem remains.

PS.

I cannot interact directly with ajax request or response and the div (with id dest), exists at page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping that code with `$(document).ready()` or angular's equivalent:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.element($("#dest")).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element($("#dest")).scope();
    $compile($("#dest"))(scope);
  });
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h787mvfp/1/).

Comment: sorry, I meant that the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
angular.element($("#dest")).injector().invoke(['$compile', function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element($("#dest")).scope();
    $compile($("#dest"))(scope);
}]);
```

Comment: if it is giving error like ' $injector:unpr ' then this solution is useful